# Ruby on rails Landing Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an extremelly basic rails 4 application. It's like a landing page with a video embeded from youtube and with a field for the user put his email and zipcode...
So, I am having trouble to save this user's email and zip code, actually, I am new at rails and I don't know how to do it... I have created a model called Information, with an email and zipcode(both strings)... I have a view called home with this code:

```
    <%= form_for :information do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :Email_address %>
       <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", :autofocus => true, placeholder: "Enter email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :Zip_Code %>
       <%= f.text_field :zipcode, class: "form-control", :autofocus => true, placeholder: "Zip Code" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But when I click submit nothing happens, I think I should create a controller but I dont know what to put on it to make it work! What should I do to collect just this two information in the best way? Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you read "Getting started" rails guide? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html I think after reading you should have knowledge to write this. There is example of a form to add comment with commenter name and body. Form for creating entry with email and zipcode will be very similar.

Answer (score 2):

You will need controller with two actions: `:new` and `:create`.
in console `rails g controller informations` (I assume your model called `Information`).
In this file

```
def new
  @information = Information.new
end

def create
  @information = Information.new(information_params)
  redirect_to @information
end

private

def information_params
 params.require(:information).permit(:email, :zipcode)
end
```

And then this code should go into `/view/informations/new` as `new.erb`

```
<%= form_for @information do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :Email_address %>
       <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", :autofocus => true, placeholder: "Enter email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :Zip_Code %>
       <%= f.text_field :zipcode, class: "form-control", :autofocus => true, placeholder: "Zip Code" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And take a look at some quick tutorial to have a basic understanding of how MVC established. This guide http://www.railstutorial.org/book is what almost everyone start.

Comment: Your `create` action will result in `MissingTemplate` error

Comment: `<%= form_for information do |f| %>` will throw exception that `undefined method: information`

Comment: Good! you have updated `form`, now update `create` action too.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain some things for you, as you're new

---

**Objects**

Ruby (& Rails by virtue of being built on Ruby) is [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). This means that every interaction you make with the Rails backend (the landing page doesn't interact with the backend initially), has to be centred around *objects*

Although you've done well by creating the respective objects (with the `Information` model), you need to appreciate the *process* of creating, populating & initializing the respecting objects

--

**Form**

You're using [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) *requires* an ActiveRecord object. This is your major downfall - say your landing page is at `application#welcome`, here's the

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def welcome
      @information = Information.new #-> creates "information" object
   end
end
```

The `form_for` method can then take the `@information` object, to populate the data as required:

```
#app/views/application/welcome.html.erb
<%= form_for @information do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :email %>
   <%= f.text_field :zipcode %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Notice how you're using the `@information` object here? This is where the ActiveRecord object comes in - allowing you to "populate" that as you wish

--

**Backend**

```
#config/routes.rb
root: "application#welcome"
resources :information, only: :create
```

The `form_for` will send your request to `information_controller.rb`:

```
#app/controllers/information_controller.rb
Class InformationController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @information = Information.new(information_params)
      if @information.save
         flash[:notice] = "Message Sent - Thank you!"
         redirect_to "application#welcome"
      end
   end

   private

   def information_params
       params.require(:information).permit(:email, :zipcode)
   end
end
```

This will be able to take the `@information` object, populate it in the database, and then redirect to the original "landing" page again.